# TypeScript, React: map array and pass down informations

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to map through an array loaded from redux store, map through and pass down the information to a new component.

This is what the object from store looks like:

```
tasks: {
    results: [
        id: number,
        name: string,
    ]
}
```

The component where the informartion will be passed down to is a simple table row:

```
interface TaskProps {id: number, name: string}

const TaskTableRow: FC<TaskProps> = ({id, name}) => {
    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td>{name}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
export default TaskTableRow
```

My table component looks similiar to this:

```
interface TaskProps {id: number, name: string}

const TaskTable = () => {

    ...        
    const tasks = useSelector((state: TasksState) => state.tasks)
    ...

    const content = tasks.results ?
        tasks.results.map<TaskProps>(
            item => <TaskTableRow id={item.id} name={item.name} />
        ) : []

    return (
        ...
        <tbody>
            { content }
        </tbody>    
        ...
    );
}
export default TaskTable
```

My idea was to access the data via `item.something`, but right now the complete `<TaskTableRow />`-Element is marked as error with the following information `TS2739: Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'TaskProps': id, name, slug, status`.

What am I missing here, or is the whole approach wrong?

Comment: Why do you put `TaskProps` here? `tasks.results.map<TaskProps>`. The argument here is a return type of the map, not the argument type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem here, you are accessing the array of `tasks` INSTEAD of the task element it self.
Because the use selector returns an array so, the array does not have the values id, names etc.(That's why there's a error) So, Here's the final code:

```js
interface TaskProps {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const TaskTable = () => {

    ...
    const tasks = useSelector((state: TasksState) => state.tasks)
        ...

        const content =
            tasks.results.map(
                item => < TaskTableRow id = {
                    item.id
                }
                name = {
                    item.name
                }
                />
            )

    return (
        ...
        <
        tbody > {
            content
        } <
        /tbody>    
        ...
    );
}
export default TaskTable;
```

Also, you have a weird data structure, you cannot have elements in a array, instead you can have a array OF OBJECTS WITH THE ELEMENTS!
So, you should change the data interface to:

```js
tasks: {
    results: [{
        id: number,
        name: string,
    } {
        id: number,
        name: string,
    } {
        id: number,
        name: string,
    } {
        id: number,
        name: string,
    }]
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped to fix my problem! Indeed it was my strange data structure.

Comment: No worries @finethen! Have a amazing day!